# Count Instances of Substrings in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
# ID  Gender
1 01  () (Male) (Female)
2 02  (Male)
3 03  (Female)
4 04  (Female) (Female)
5 05  (Male) (Male) (Male)
```

For each instance, I would like to add three new columns:

```
# ID Gender Gender-Male Gender-Female Gender-Null
```

Each of these columns counts how many () (Male) and (Female) substrings are in the instance. Essentially this means that for the instance, 3 Men participated in that session, or 2 Women and 1 Null Entity, etc.

What is the best way to achieve this? A "for" loop with regex? Or is there some better library I should be using?

Comment: Honestly, you'd be better off normalizing your data, and getting each gender/ID occurrence onto a separate row in the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Replace `()` with `Null` in Gender and remove the parentheses in Gender.  Then separate Gender into rows and for each ID and Gender tally the number of rows.  Finally spread that back out into wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

counts <- DF %>%
  mutate(Gender = gsub("()", "Null", Gender, fixed = TRUE), 
         Gender = gsub("[()]", "", Gender)) %>%
  separate_rows(Gender) %>%
  count(ID, Gender) %>%
  spread(Gender, n, fill = 0)

left_join(DF, counts)
```

giving:

```
  # ID               Gender Female Male Null
1 1  1   () (Male) (Female)      1    1    1
2 2  2               (Male)      0    1    0
3 3  3             (Female)      1    0    0
4 4  4    (Female) (Female)      2    0    0
5 5  5 (Male) (Male) (Male)      0    3    0
```

**2)** or using only base R split the Gender strings into a list of separate strings `spl` and then stack them into a data frame `long`.  Finally tabulate that with `xtabs`.

```
spl <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(DF$Gender), " "), DF$ID)
long <- setNames(stack(spl), c("Gender", "ID"))
counttab <- xtabs(~ ID + Gender, long)

merge(DF, cbind(ID = rownames(counttab), as.data.frame.matrix(counttab)))
```

giving:

```
  ID #               Gender () (Female) (Male)
1  1 1   () (Male) (Female)  1        1      1
2  2 2               (Male)  0        0      1
3  3 3             (Female)  0        1      0
4  4 4    (Female) (Female)  0        2      0
5  5 5 (Male) (Male) (Male)  0        0      3
```

### Note

We used this as the input:

```
Lines <- "#,ID,Gender
1,01,() (Male) (Female)
2,02,(Male)
3,03,(Female)
4,04,(Female) (Female)
5,05,(Male) (Male) (Male)"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
```